# Is there a way to use a program wrote in c# 2010 , at Windows Embedded?

Tags: c#, windows-embedded

at first my English is not good,so please forgive me for any bad using of words.

I am a programmer(a New one), i wrote a program in C# 2010 with .NET4 , this program gets Video from a Webcam (With Aforge) ,Gets some Code from Wireless network and then shows the Received code and Captured Video on screen and then send the code via SerialPort (RS232) to a Micro Controller, and sends the Captured Video To a server via Wireless, And it works correctly. (it's a program for a Robot)

Now the question is:
my Master told me he has a computer with a Windows (he told me it has Windows Embedded), now my question is what is the windows Embedded & How can i Use my program on this windows?

Thanks.

Arta Afkandeh.

Comment: Which windows embedded is your customer using?

Answer (score 3):

According to the windows embedded version the customer should be able to install the matching .Net framework, so if his oprerating system is allowing .Net 4 your programm should work on it. take a look at these links:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-standard-7.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255(WinEmbedded.5).aspx
http://www.elbacom.com/blog/2010/11/net-4-0-framework-template-available